# JTable column headers localization

Tags: java, localization, header, jtable

I have a subclass of javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel that defines table column headers like this: `protected String[] columnNames = new String[] { "Column1", "Column2};`. How do I localize the `columnNames` from a resource bundle? I want to read the column headers from a .properties file instead on hard-coding them in my code. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to modify your assignment of columnNames:

```
protected String[] columnNames = getColumnNames();
//...
private static String[] getColumnNames() {
  return ResourceBundle.getBundle("AppResources").getString("headings").split(",");
}
```

Where AppResources (or AppResources_en, AppResources_fr_FR etc.) is a class that extends ResourceBundle and contains a key called "headings" which returns a comma separated list of headings.

Comment: I fixed the weird-looking stuff in the code but I think packing multiple strings into a single string and then splitting them apart at runtime is a bad idea because when you finally send this to your translators, they should translate the commas into commas for their own language, so your splitting code won't work anymore. What you should be doing is putting one header name into each string.

Answer (score 3):

You override the `getColumnName()` in order to return the localized value of the column name.

For example :

```
private ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyResource");

@Override
public String getColumnName( int column ) {
    return res.getString(columnNames[column]);
}
```